# How to plot many columns at once in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame with many columns. The first column contains categories such as "System 1", "System 2", and the second column has numbers that represent the 0's and 1's.

For example:

| SYSTEM | Q1 | Q2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| S1 | 0 | 1 |
| S1 | 1 | 0 |
| S2 | 1 | 1 |
| S2 | 0 | 0 |
| S2 | 1 | 1 |

How to write R code to produce a violin plot for all the questions(Q1,Q2,Q3,..Q10) at the same time.

```
p <- ggplot(mydata, aes(x =system, y = q1, fill=system, color=system)) +
ggplot(mydata, aes(x =system, y = q2, fill=system, color=system)) +
ggplot(mydata, aes(x =system, y = q3, fill=system, color=system)) +
ggplot(mydata, aes(x =system, y = q100, fill=system, color=system)) +
 geom_violin(show.legend=FALSE) +
 stat_summary(fun.y=median, geom="point", size=2, color="red")+
  coord_flip()

save pdf file 

filename <- fs::path(knitr::fig_path(),  "file.pdf")

 ggsave(filename)
 

plot(p)
invisible(dev.off())
knitr::include_graphics(filename)
```

I'm new to R and I spent a very long time but it doesn't work at all.

I apply the code suggested by @Rui Barradas then I got all the plots compare to each other. Actually, what I want is to get one figure that include 2 plots for each system such system 1 then system 2 side by side and the title is Q1.

Pleas I asked for how to save pdf files for each figure by using for-loop to save 100 pdf files in a folder.

Thank you again.

Comment: A violin plot for binomial data? Not a good use of plotting resources.

Answer (score 3):

This type of problems generally has to do with reshaping the data. The format should be the long format and the data is in wide format. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format) on how to reshape the data from wide to long format.

Violin plots are not meant for binary data, you would have hour-glass type of plots, full at the extremes 0 and 1, slim in the middle. Try a dot plot instead.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(ggplot2)
  library(dplyr)
  library(tidyr)
})

df2 %>%
  pivot_longer(-SYSTEM, names_to = "QUESTION") %>% 
  group_by(SYSTEM, QUESTION) %>%
  summarise(Count = sum(value), .groups = "drop") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(SYSTEM, QUESTION)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = Count, color = Count)) +
  guides(color = guide_legend()) +
  labs(size = "Count", color = "Count") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

A violin plot would look like the following.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(ggplot2)
  library(dplyr)
  library(tidyr)
})

df2 %>%
  pivot_longer(-SYSTEM, names_to = "QUESTION") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(QUESTION, value)) +
  geom_violin() +
  facet_wrap(~ SYSTEM) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit

To have a violin plot (once again, a bad idea for binary data) of `SYSTEM` vs. values, with one `QUESTION` per panel, just swap the relevant variables in the code above, `SYSTEM` and `QUESTION`.
I have also edited the y axis label, `"Distribution"` is more descriptive of what the plot is representing.

```r
df2 %>%
  pivot_longer(-SYSTEM, names_to = "QUESTION") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(SYSTEM, value)) +
  geom_violin() +
  ylab("Distrubution") +
  facet_wrap(~ QUESTION) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Data

Here I make the posted data bigger.

```r
x<-"SYSTEM  Q1  Q2
S1  0   1
S1  1   0
S2  1   1
S2  0   0
S2  1   1"
df1 <- read.table(textConnection(x), header = TRUE)

n <- 1e4
df2 <- data.frame(
  SYSTEM = sample(df1$SYSTEM, n, TRUE),
  Q1 = sample(df1$Q1, n, TRUE),
  Q2 = sample(df1$Q2, n, TRUE)
)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>